# Y coordinate being rounded to tenth

Tags: sql, geometry, sql-server

I'm having an issue where the Y coordinate in a UTM is being rounded to the nearest 10th, and I don't know why.

I have a SQL Server Database with a view that is using columns from a table in another database through a linked server.  This view has an extra SHAPE column in which I computer the POINT from the X and Y columns in table. I'm using this formula to create the Geometry,

```
geometry::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(X_UTM_NAD83Z14_D AS VARCHAR(20)) 
                      + ' ' + CAST(Y_UTM_NAD83Z14_D AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 26914) AS SHAPE
```

The columns X_UTM_NAD83Z14_D and Y_UTM_NAD83Z14_D are float datatype

The problem was noticed when it was compared to original points and a temporary layer was made directly from the source table.  The X direction was fine, but the Y direction was being rounded to the nearest tenth and thus shifting all the points north or south a maximum of 5 meters.

Original Coordinate: 335688.2, 6067867.1
PointFromText Coordinate: 335688.2, 6067870.0

Could someone help me figure this out?  I don't understand where the error is coming from.

Comment: Does this error happen when using the STR function instead of cast? The description of the STR function is in this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx

Comment: Thanks!  That did the trick.  STR(Y_UTM_NAD83Z14_D, 20, 2).  Do you know why CAST had the behavior it did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why, but this behaviour is documented on the official documentation: 
Cast may truncate your results:

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx:

> Conversions to char, varchar, nchar, nvarchar, binary, and varbinary
>   are truncated, except for the conversions shown in the following
>   table.

The function STR is designed for converting float expressions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx

```
STR ( float_expression [ , length [ , decimal ] ] )
```

From that article, it seems there are other options as well. I did not test them.
http://www.connectsql.com/2011/04/normal-0-microsoftinternetexplorer4.html

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me to where I should have looked in the first place!